# adding comma to textarea values while scanning from barcode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing barcode scanning and inserting the values of that barcode into the `textarea`. The problem being, it is inserting values without any comma or space.

I have tried using `textarea` like this:

```
<textarea 
  onpropertychange="addCommas(this.value);" 
  onpaste="addCommas(this.value);" 
  autofocus 
  name="bar" 
  id="bar" 
  rows="5"
 >
 </textarea>
```

I have not written the function and I don't know how to do it. I am using the events specific to IE so at least I can try that it should work but I am confused as while I scan and it pastes data in the textarea, the textarea needs to know and adds a comma.

I scan the barcode but all values are coming as `1234567890`, I want it to be in this format when in textarea: `12345,67890`

Comment: the barcodes aways have the same length?

Comment: provide your addComma() method code.

Comment: So, you want to format the entry, before it is submitted?

Comment: How are you inserting the barcode into the text area? Are you using a handheld scanner emulating a keyboard? Or do you use a specific API? Please provide the code for your `addCommas` function, and add logs or breakpoints into that function to check if/when it’s actually called.

Answer (score 0):

You could use barcode scanning Detection

jQuery Scanner Detection
https://plugins.jquery.com/scannerdetection/

**SCRIPT**

```
$(window).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).scannerDetection();
    $(window).bind('scannerDetectionComplete',function(e,data){
        console.log('complete '+data.string);
        $("#bCode").val(data.string);
    })
    .bind('scannerDetectionError',function(e,data){
        console.log('detection error '+data.string);
    })
    .bind('scannerDetectionReceive',function(e,data){
        console.log('Recieve');
        console.log(data.evt.which);
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id='bCode'type='text' value='barcode appears here'/>
```

**For additional Information and Usages**

Tutorial for usage and best practices, as well discussed about various Barcode Scanner Models and how to deal with it. http://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-scannerdetection-tutorial.html